# jQuery - using calculation + variables in a function to change css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, variables

I´ve written this code to get a dynamic margin as heigh as my header is:

```
  $(window).on("resize", function() {
    var divHeight = $('#header').innerHeight();
    $('body > .container').css('padding-top', divHeight + 'px');
  }).resize();
```

now I would like to give some other elements the same variable, f.ex. my navigation but the css height have to be:

```
height: calc(100% - 'VARIABLE FROM CODE ABOVE');
```

Do you have any suggestions how I can get this working?
Thanks for all who read this :)

Comment: Why not access it again in the same way? `var divHeight = $('#header').innerHeight();`

Comment: I would like to do it the same way but I dont know how to write it, i tried this:
 $('#header').css('height', calc(divHeight + 'px)');

Comment: What variable are you trying to access again? What do you want tot do exactly? it isn't very clear to me.

Comment: I would like to give my #navigation width: 100% + the width from another div(the #header)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an solution:

```
  $(window).on("resize", function() {
    var divHeight = $('#header').innerHeight();
    $('body > .container').css('padding-top', divHeight + 'px');
    $('#navigation').css('margin-top', divHeight + 'px');
    $('#navigation').css('height', 'calc( 100% - ' + divHeight + 'px)')
  }).resize();
```